# mongoDB query has got error

Tags: mongodb-query

I have written a query in mongoDB and got an error. Please some one help me in resolving it
Query is:

```
> db.Accounts.update(_id:t.source,pendingTransaction:{$ne:t._id}},{$inc:{balance
:-t.value},$push:{pendingTransactions:t._id}});
```

ERROR IS:

```
2014-10-10T20:27:02.861+0530 SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Comment: I am not getting where did I write an extra colon( : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

db.Accounts.update(**{**   the { is missing ...

```
db.Accounts.update({
 _id:t.source,
  pendingTransaction:{$ne:t._id}},
{$inc:{balance
:-t.value},$push:{pendingTransactions:t._id}});
```

Comment: Thanx alot.. :) Will accept your answer in a short while